# Why does merge result in more rows than original data?

Tags: r, join

When I `merge` two data frames, the result has more rows than the original data.

In this instance, the **all** dataframe has **104956 rows**, **koppen** has **3968 rows** and **alltest** dataframe has **130335 rows**. Ordinarily, alltest should have had rows equal to or less than **all**.

Why is this inflation happening? I am not sure if giving the reproducible example would help as it does work in the previous instances I have used it.

```
alltest <- merge(all, koppen, by = "fips", sort = F)
```

Comment: Probably because one of the two dataframes had duplicate values of `fips`.

Comment: Oh wait, there are duplicate FIPS in the ALL ofcourse. It is not supposed to be unique. Any idea how can I can merge without increasing these rows?

Comment: try `merge(all,koppen,by="fips",sort=F, all.x = T)`

Comment: Does `nrow(koppen)==length(unique(koppen$fips))` return `TRUE`? If not, then there are duplicated values of `fips`

Comment: How would you merge them unambiguously without increasing the number of rows?

Comment: @jlhoward Thanks. That returns a FALSE. Also, this returns a FALSE as well. nrow(all)==length(unique(all$fips))

Comment: @beginneR Tried that before. Doesn't work.

Comment: The latter result is not surprising - as you say `all` should have duplicated `fips`. But `koppen` should not, so there is bug somewhere. You are getting all these rows because of the duplicated `koppen$fips`.

Comment: True. I am using this data: http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/data/KoeppenGeiger.UScounty.txt Any piece of code to detect the non-unique values? Also, can I remove all but 1 (first one) instance of the overlapping rows. Thanks

Comment: Or is there a way to do this without removing duplicate rows? I am sure this is not a one-off problem and can imagine a lot of datasets where this may be an issue. I am not limited to using merge.

Comment: "I am not sure if giving the reproducible example would help as it does work in the previous instances I have used it." A reproducible example should reproduce the issue you're having.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, from `?merge`:

> The rows in the two data frames that match on the specified columns are extracted, and joined together. If there is *more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each*.

Using your link in the comments:

```
url    <- "http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/data/KoeppenGeiger.UScounty.txt"
koppen <- read.table(url, header=T, sep="\t")
nrow(koppen)
# [1] 3594
length(unique(koppen$FIPS))
# [1] 2789
```

So clearly `koppen` has duplicated FIPS codes. Examining the dataset and the website, it appears that many of the counties are in more than one climate class, so for example, the county of Ankorage, Alaska has three climate classes:

```
koppen[koppen$FIPS==2020,]
#     STATE    COUNTY FIPS CLS  PROP
# 73 Alaska Anchorage 2020 Dsc 0.010
# 74 Alaska Anchorage 2020 Dfc 0.961
# 75 Alaska Anchorage 2020  ET 0.029
```

The solution depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to extract all rows in `all` with any `FIPS` that appear in `koppen`, either of these should work:

```
merge(all,unique(koppen$FIPS))

all[all$FIPS %in% unique(koppen$FIPS),]
```

If you need to append the county and state name to `all`, use this:

```
merge(all,unique(koppen[c("STATE","COUNTY","FIPS")]),by="FIPS")
```

**EDIT** Based on the exchange below in the comments.

So, since there are sometimes multiple rows in `koppen` with the same `FIPS`, but different `CLS`, we need a way to decide which of the rows (e.g., which `CLS`) to pick. Here are two ways:

```
# this extracts the row with the largest value of PROP, for that FIPS
url        <- "http://koeppen-geiger.vu-wien.ac.at/data/KoeppenGeiger.UScounty.txt"
koppen     <- read.csv(url, header=T, sep="\t")
koppen     <- with(koppen,koppen[order(FIPS,-PROP),])
sub.koppen <- aggregate(koppen,by=list(koppen$FIPS),head,n=1)
result     <- merge(all, sub.koppen, by="FIPS")

# this extracts a row at random
sub.koppen <- aggregate(koppen,by=list(koppen$FIPS), 
                        function(x)x[sample(1:length(x),1)])
result     <- merge(all, sub.koppen, by="FIPS")
```

Comment: Ok, one problem..I definitely need the class as well. When I am usingmerge(all,unique(koppen[c("STATE","COUNTY","CLASS","FIPS")]),by="FIPS") , it is again more than required rows. But the code works fine when I only use state, county, fips. Why is that?

Comment: There can be more than one class for a given FIPS. Which class do you want? If you want all of them, then there will be duplicated FIPS.

Comment: Whichever row in *koppen* from which *all* reads a particular FIPS (one of the many occurrences of it), I want the corresponding class.

Comment: Any clue on this sir?

Comment: So `all` has a `CLS` column as well? Do you want rows in `all` where both `FIPS` and `CLS` match in `koppen`?

Comment: ALL has no CLS column. Now that I have FIPS in ALL, all I need are the corresponding CLS *FROM* Koppen as a column in All. I am guessing the way it works is, MERGE matches FIPS in ALL with FIPS in Koppen. So whichever FIPS it read in Koppen, I want the corresponding CLS. Hope I am not rambling too much.

Comment: The problem is that, for a given FIPS, there is *more than one CLS* in `koppen`. So if you want all of them, you will get more than one row per FIPS in the merge. Take Ankorage, from my example. If `all` has one row with FIPS=2020, and you want all three CLS from `koppen`, then you will have three rows in the merge for FIPS=2020. If `all` has multiple rows with FIPS=2020, then you will have three rows in the result *for every row in `all` with FIPS=2020*.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. We faced the same problem with multiple FIPS, didn't we? How does your piece of code decide which one to pick? For example, koppen[koppen$FIPS==2020,]. How did it decide between the three?

Comment: I want to follow the same strategy as with multiple FIPS. Just need one class (even random would do. Or maybe the first match. Or the CLS that occurs maximum times). For example, in your example,Dsc occurs twice and ET occurs only once, so I would choose Dsc. Please help if you can. I appreciate it so much. :)