# Extra Observations When Merging Datasets

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two datasets (Datasets A and B) but when I merge Dataset A (407 Obs) with Dataset B (1462 Obs) I merged them by:

```
C <- merge(A, B, by=ID, all.x=TRUE)
```

It creates 416 observations in Dataset C.

Is there a reason why?

Answer (score 0):

See [Why does the result from merge have more rows than original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150765/why-does-the-result-from-merge-have-more-rows-than-original-file).

Looks like there were multiple matches in the ID column. Since you didn't specify what your goal is, I recommend going through the full documentation:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/merge