# Duplicated rows after reshaping and joining

Tags: r

I am  analyzing the student test data, but before that I want to tidy it. I tried to build a tidy data frame but it seems like the rows are duplicating. Below is my code.

```
library(tidyverse)
(Test <- tibble(
  Student = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Test1 = c("SAT", "SAT", "SAT", "SAT", "SAT"),
  Test2 = c("NA", "ACT", "ACT", "ACT", "ACT"),
  testdate1 = c("7/1/2017", "6/1/2017", "3/1/2017", "2/17/2018", "NA"),
  testdate2 = c("NA", "NA", "1/1/2016", "12/1/2016", "10/1/2016")
))


(Testa <- tibble(
  Student = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Test1 = c("SAT", "SAT", "SAT", "SAT", "SAT"),
  Test2 = c("NA", "ACT", "ACT", "ACT", "ACT")
))


(Testb <- tibble(
  Student = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  testdate1 = c("7/1/2017", "6/1/2017", "3/1/2017", "2/17/2018", "NA"),
  testdate2 = c("NA", "NA", "1/1/2016", "12/1/2016", "10/1/2016")
))

(td1 <- Testa %>% 
    gather(Test1, Test2, key = "Test", value = "Score"))
(td2 <- Testb %>% 
    gather(testdate1, testdate2, key = "Dated", value = "Datev"))
(tidy <- left_join(td1, td2))
```

Can anyone please help me solve this issue. Below is the image of how I want to see the data.

[image]

Comment: If the ids are not unique in each of the joining datasets, it would result in duplication

Comment: Similar for `base::merge`: [Why does the result from merge have more rows than original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150765/why-does-the-result-from-merge-have-more-rows-than-original-file) with possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I think I figured it out. I am using this                                                                                                       tidy %>% 
  distinct(Student, Datev, .keep_all = TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an id for the students and an id for the tests

See if this can help

```
td1 <- Testa %>% 
     gather(Test1, Test2, key = "Test", value = "Score")

td2 <- Testb %>%
     gather(testdate1, testdate2, key = "Dated", value = "Datev") %>%
     mutate(Test=ifelse(Dated %in% "testdate1", "Test1", "Test2"))
tidy <- left_join(td1, td2)
tidy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use `stats::reshape` which is capable of gathering multiple columns, as suggested in answers to this question:

[Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

The interface of `stats:reshape` is not as beautiful as the tidy-interfaces, but it gets the job done in one function call.