# Join to get coverage on movil network operators at a state level

Tags: r, join, merge, tidyverse, tidycensus

fdb is [this](https://www.fcc.gov/general/broadband-deployment-data-fcc-form-477) file and I need to join it with number of HHs by block group but it's not working as [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-dataframes-by-column-names-in-r/#:%7E:text=The%20merge()%20function%20in,in%20the%20input%20function%20call.) says it will because the number of census blocks (12 first in BlockCode) at the end isn't as many after merging as it says it is at the begginig, I was expecting that this join would give me 226773. This isn't as if [it was merging more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150765/why-does-merge-result-in-more-rows-than-original-data) but it's giving me less and I can't find the right lead. I really don't understand the pieces where it gives me more than 239780 Census blocks they are according to tidyCensus. Could someone please?

```
library(tidycensus)
fdb <- read.csv("fbd_us_with_satellite_dec2020_v1.csv") 

abbr <- c("AL","AK","AZ","AR","CA","CO","CT","DE","DC","FL","GA","HI","ID","IL","IN","IA","KS","KY","LA","ME","MD","MA","MI","MN","MS","MO","MT","NE","NV",
          "NH","NJ","NM","NY","NC","ND","OH","OK","OR","PA","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VT","VA","WA","WV","WI","WY") # 51 states
HH_units <- get_acs(geography = "block group", variables = c(households = "B25001_001"), state = abbr) # same as B01003_001 for income level # HHs 
HH_units$households <- HH_units$estimate

library(dplyr)
HH_units <- HH_units %>%
  select(
    GEOID,
    NAME,
    households
  )

unique(fdb$BlockCode) # 11164855 rows
fdb$GEOID <- substring(fdb$BlockCode, 1, 12)
unique(fdb$GEOID) # it's got 226773 block lines

# Apparently you got to increase R's memory limit to join huge data sets
memory.limit()               
memory.limit(400000)

all <- merge(x = fdb,
             y = HH_units,
             by = "GEOID")
unique(all$GEOID) # 138625 rows and not 226773

all2 <- full_join(x = fdb,
                  y = HH_units,
                  by = "GEOID") 
unique(all2$GEOID) # 326928 

all3 <- right_join(x = fdb,
                   y = HH_units,
                   by = "GEOID") 
unique(all3$GEOID) # 239780
```